# HTML Link to Send SMS to Multiple Recipients in Google Messages

Tags: android, html, sms

I am trying to add a link on my website to send a text message to multiple recipients. The format I am using is:

```
<a href="sms://1111111111, 2222222222;?&body=Hello%20World">Send</a>
```

However on my android phone (using the Google Messages app) this does not work and only sends to the first number. Is there a format that Google Messages will accept to send SMS to multiple recipients?